# mysql subtraction from different rows in same column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for mileage records. Like this sample one. I need to calculate mileage usage for particular month.

```
Date            Meter
---------------------
2014-01-01      12500
2014-01-12      12650
2014-02-01      13000
2014-02-15      13350
2014-03-01      15000
```

I need an answer for example: for `January` the result is `500` (from the subtraction `13000-12500`) or for `February` the reuslt is `2000` (`15000-13000`).

I tried the following but I'm getting the wrong answer. How do I get about this? Thank you.

```
select (select Meter from tbl where Date = '2014-12-01') - 
       (select Meter from tbl where Date = '2014-11-01');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t1.`Date`) AS month,
       t2.Meter - t1.Meter
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t2.`Date` =  DATE_ADD(t1.`Date`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM t1.`Date`) = 1
```

This should work as long as you have one record for each 1st day of month date.

Comment: Getting error 1064 (42000) in sql syntax. Only I have to change is table name and real date instead of Date?

Comment: @Gamini I've tested the query and it runs ok on my end. I don't know about the actual schema of your table, It can't be that hard to adjust it though.

Comment: 1 ID int(2)   No  0 
 2 SDATE date   Yes  NULL
 3 OMETER varchar(5) 4 AMOUNT decimal(4,2)   Yes  NULL  Change Change Drop Drop 

    Primary Primary
    Unique Unique
    Index Index
    Spatial Spatial
    Fulltext Fulltext
    Distinct values Distinct values

 5 VOLUME decimal(4,2)   Yes  NULL  Change Change Drop Drop 

    Primary Primary
    Unique Unique
    Index Index
    Spatial Spatial
    Fulltext Fulltext
    Distinct values Distinct values

 6 PLACE varchar(13) utf8_general_ci  Yes  NULL  Change Change Drop Drop

Comment: right syntax to use near ''sdate') as month, t2.ometer - t1.ometer from auto as t1 join auto as t2 on t2.'' at line 1